# Why device manager is showing 4 Network adapters and how to remove them?

Tags: windows-7, device-manager, usb-network-adapter

I am seeing 4 network adapters in Device manager. What are these? I don't think i have all these adapters.

[image]

What are these *virtual wifi miniport adapters* ? I remember i removed them but i am seeing those again. How to remove the adapters from the list which i don't have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Virtual adapters are part of Windows, and will return when deleted when you go to use your wifi card (The Intel wifi link). The Broadcom is your Ethernet connection. I would recommend leavin all four in there and not worrying about the extra two, unless they show up with a yellow exclamation point

Comment: My system freezes when i try to connect to wifi second time. I read on some site that having multiple network adapter can cause this issue. Anyways i will create another question asking about this freezing problem.

Comment: @Rakesh Absolutely, you should. I haven't heard of that issue though, so I'll probably star it for reference

Comment: That would generally only be for multiple PHYSICAL network adapters. These are not physical adapters and so would probably not be the cause of such an issue.